Correct sudoers configuration syntax to allow a group of user access to specific tools (any arguments)
I am attempting to request extra privileges for my developers on our enterprise system.  The admins expect me to submit the sudoers entry.  Since I don't have root privileges, I have no way of testing this in advance so I am looking for help.
What I want is allow all users in a given group to execute tcpdump, nc, and netstat with any arguments.  It seems like something like this might work.  Is this correct?
Cmnd_alias    PACKET_MONITORING = /usr/sbin/tcpdump,  /usr/bin/nc, /usr/bin/netstat
%developers    PACKET_MONITORING = NOPASSWD: ALL


@user2233709 It will work the same way on any Linux machine with sudo installed. They could test it in a VM. However, the did not want help with testing but with syntax. I believe the syntax of the second line is wrong (commands go last), but I too would have needed to test it on a real system to be sure. I find it slightly strange that they (those admins) are expecting a correctly crafted configuration fragment. Surely they can think for themselves and write it from a description?

Unfortunately the admin's want us to do about 80% of their job for them.  In most cases this isn't and issue, but I don't have a lot of experience with the sudoers file.

%developers    PACKET_MONITORING = NOPASSWD: ALL

means that users in the developers group are allowed to run all commands on hosts in the PACKET_MONITORING.
The man page has e.g. this example:

jack      CSNETS = ALL
The user jack may run any command on the machines in the CSNETS alias

And on the other hand, these two:

Cmnd_Alias     PRINTING = /usr/sbin/lpc, /usr/bin/lprm
+secretaries   ALL = PRINTING, /usr/bin/adduser, /usr/bin/rmuser
Users in the secretaries netgroup need to help manage the printers as well as add and remove users, so they are allowed to run those commands on all machines.

I.e. the part before the = lists the hosts the rule applies on, and the part after lists the commands. So I'm pretty sure yours should be like so:
Cmnd_Alias    PACKET_MONITORING = /usr/sbin/tcpdump, /usr/bin/nc, /usr/bin/netstat
%developers   ALL = NOPASSWD: PACKET_MONITORING

I'm not sure if sudo is picky about letter case, but the A in Cmnd_Alias  is uppercase in the man page.
